# Running Linear Regression Model

Tags: regression, time-series, logistic

my question is can i run linear regression model using summarized counts/frequencies? For example, my dependent variable is total number of people who is aware of a specific TV show and my independent variable is total number of people who said that the specific program is good.The total number of TV programs is 100. If yes, how do i interpret it? Is it the same as with the normal GLM? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the objectives and or hypothesis ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generalised linear model to fit count data. This is sometimes called Poisson regression. You use a log link. I assume by GLM you meant the general linear model not the generalised linear model. You do not say what software you are planning on using but these models are available in any respectable package.